# Is there a QWidget which visualizes something like this "first |1|2|3...30|31|33| last"

Tags: c++11, qt5

I suppose everyone has used these, but I don't know how they are called, so I couldn't really search for them. Their behaviour is as follows: one can click on "first" or "last" or anything in between to navigate to a certain page.

Does anyone know if there exists some kind of QWidget which does that? Maybe similar to a combo-box where one can select something and a signal with the selected index is emitted?

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time david

Comment: I think the term pagination may help you google

Comment: @yankee2905 Thank you for the hint. It seems no such widget exists, according to my google-search and the answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, QT does not provide a widget with the capabilities you are looking for. It should be relatively simple to recreate using `QButtonGroup` and a styled set of`QPushButton`s or re-implemented `QABstractPushButtons`.